# PrimeNg (7.x) p-dropdown boolean value

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I would like to have a **p-dropdown** that contains two options.
But the items do not get selected based on the control **boolean value**.

**The control (NOTIF_ALL) receive a boolean value**

```
oldPendingTasksOptions=[
 {"oldPendingTaskId": false, "oldPendingTasksName": "Not activated", "version": 1},
 {"oldPendingTaskId": true, "oldPendingTasksName": "Activated", "version": 1}
 ]


<p-dropdown [options]="oldPendingTasksOptions"
  [showClear]="true"
  placeholder="Select an option"
  optionLabel="oldPendingTasksName"
  formControlName="NOTIF_ALL"></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convinced the client that a radio was better ;)